# what is the Correct way to use try catch in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a bunch of stored procedures for add, update and delete in a database I am doing ass a project for school. I want to use try catch and a flag to tell the user if there was success or not. I am using SQL server 2005, I have the basic stored procedures down but want to add this to make my project better. I keep getting a SQL error improper syntax near keyword set.
 Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.addCustomer 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@flag bit output, --return 1 for success and 0 for fail
@Customer_ID varchar(50),
@sales_region varchar(50),
@Items_Recieved varchar(max),
@Hual_ID varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
INSERT into dbo.Customer(Customer_ID,Sales_region, Items_Recieved, Hual_ID)
values(@Customer_ID,@sales_region, @Items_Recieved, @Hual_ID  
set @flag=1;
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
BEGIN commit TRANSACTION;
END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
BEGIN rollback TRANSACTION;
END

set @flag=0;
END CATCH
END

GO
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction, I am sure I did something simple wrong, or forgot to do something.
Thanks.

Comment: You are missing `);` in your insert statement before `set @flag=1`, it should be `values(@Customer_ID,@sales_region, @Items_Recieved, @Hual_ID);`

Comment: gah! I see that now. sometimes I look at code for so long that I cannot find the simple mistakes. I assume I am doing something wrong with logic. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.addCustomer 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@flag bit output, --return 1 for success and 0 for fail
@Customer_ID varchar(50),
@sales_region varchar(50),
@Items_Recieved varchar(max),
@Hual_ID varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;               
 BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO dbo.Customer(Customer_ID,Sales_region, Items_Recieved, Hual_ID)
        VALUES(@Customer_ID,@sales_region, @Items_Recieved, @Hual_ID)  
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

       SET @flag=1;
  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH
      IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
       BEGIN 
         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
       END

    SET @flag=0; 
     --  Utilise your other Error Functions to get detailed 
     -- Information about the Error, function like 
     --  ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_NUMBER()....
  END CATCH

END
GO
```

Comment: M.Ali if I want to use the ERROR_MESSAGE() to display a custom message, can I store a string in there and ultimately float it up to the client to be displayed in a nice wrapper? or is that only a SQL error message to be displayed in the management studio console?

Comment: You can use the your custom error messages of sql server built in messages it entirely depends on you, but please look closer at the logic I have used in my solution, You only open the transaction when you are actually doing the insert, no need to open the transaction even before you have entered the `Try Block`, Once you have opened the transaction, commit it straight away no need to check for open transactions, If something goes wrong in Try block control will jump to catch block there you need to check for open transactions and roll back if any tran is open and do your other error handling.

Comment: Oh now I see what you are saying, thank you. That does make much more sense. Your logic is actually using the try catch to catch errors because the transaction does not open until I am doing my insert, thus enabling my try catch to handle an error. Very helpful, I get it.